# Efficent addition of indices to 2d-arrays of various sizes

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

If one had a set of 2d-arrays of different dimensions, say:

```
float[][] P = new float[2][3];
float[][] B = new float[2][2];
float[][] A = new float[32][2];
float[] E = new float[2];
```

currently holding no values.

Is it possible to add values to each index of the arrays by looping through the index values of the largest collective dimensions (in this case):

```
for (int i=0; i<32; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
         //doSomething to (P[i][j]) if P has this index
         //doSomething to (B[i][j]) if B has this index
         //doSomething to (A[i][j]) if A has this index
         //doSomething to (E[i][j]) if E has this index         
    }
}
```

Otherwise, one must have four separate loops!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<32; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
         if(i < 2)
           doSomething(P[i][j]);
         if(i < 2 && j < 2)
           doSomething(B[i][j]);
         if(j < 2)
           doSomething(A[i][j]);
         if(i == 0 && j < 2)
           doSomething(E[i][j]);         
    }
}
```

You need the `i == 0` part for `E` because you only want to modify everything once, not 32 times. Note that only `B` needs two conditions because the other conditions are enforced by the `for` loop.